# Trying to identify this chip

Tags: integrated-circuit

[image: Unknown chip]

Tried all kinds of searches (including https://www.alldatasheet.com/ by marking), no result.
Can't even identify the manufacturer logo (PI-like symbol).

Comment: The manufacturer logo is STMicroelectronics - see [this image](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Kramer_Electronics_SID-X1N_-_board_-_STMicroelectronics_ST3232C-5544.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/memories/serial-eeprom/standard-serial-eeprom/standard-microwire-eeprom/m93c46-w.html
PS:Sorry Robert, I do not yet have the right to comment